# What is the more reliable way, using the Win32 API, to determine if a processor is an Intel Skylake Gen?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

What is the most reliable way, using the Win32 API, to determine if a processor is an Intel Skylake Gen? This seems like an easy question, as one can check the friendly name of the CPU in the registry and get some data, but I have found that to be less than authoritative and feel I am missing some other store of data to query.

Note: I specified the Win32 API to both be clear this is Windows, and also to deter answers that would involve writing a device driver (interfacing with them via deviceioctrl/IRP is fine).

Thanks!

Comment: Not using the win32 api but you should be able to use the __cpuid intrinsic to get the CPU information and determine it from that?

Comment: Thank you! I found this page helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most reliable / direct way is to use the [CPUID instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CPUID.html) with the appropriate input register values, and decode the vendor/family/model ID numbers.

According to http://www.sandpile.org/x86/cpuid.htm,

SKL has Family = 0x6 (like every descendant of i686 PPro (P6 core)).

- SKL Y/U: model = 0x4E (low power, dual-core even for i7)
- SKL S/H: model = 0x5E (desktop/high-power laptop, quad-core except i3)
- SKX model = 0x55 (Skylake-E Xeons, not release yet AFAIK)
- KBL Y/U: model = 0x8E (Kaby Lake low power, dual-core)
- KBL S/H: model = 0x9E (Kaby Lake desktop/high-power laptop, quad-core except i3)

Dual-core desktop i3 CPUs are probably the same die as quad-core i5, but with 2 of the cores disabled.  (Often because of a manufacturing defect that would prevent it being sold as a quad-core part.)  Interesting to see that the model # reflects this difference between dual-core silicon vs. a quad-core die fused-off to dual-core.

---

If there's something you want to enable based on something Skylake has, it might be better to detect that directly (with some other CPUID query).  e.g. check the feature-bit for an instruction-set extension directly.  That way you won't run into trouble in a VM where CPUID shows a SKL CPU, but the VM doesn't pass through all instruction-set extensions.  (e.g. some don't pass through AVX to the guest OS).

But this might be useful if you're selecting between versions of a function tuned for Haswell vs. Skylake.  e.g. `psrlvd ymm, ymm, ymm` is 1 uop / 1 cycle on Skylake, but 3 uops and 3 cycles on Haswell.  So on Haswell, repeated shifts by the same amount (when it isn't a compile-time-constant) would be faster if you use `psrld ymm, ymm, xmm` (with the count in the low element of the xmm reg), but on Skylake it's faster to pre-broadcast the shift count and use a variable-shift.

There are other improvements to front-end throughput, micro-fusion of indexed addressing modes, and instructions running on more ports that could make it useful to have differently micro-optimized versions of things for  Skylake vs. Haswell.

Comment: Thanks! This helps expand the module's capabilities considerably. I think it is preferably to my early (though sufficient) way of determining based on supported CPU features. For me, that was enough though, but I'm going to expand our code to use these family identifiers. I appreciate you documenting a few common and new ones for me!

Answer (score 1):

(answering my own question) 
While no available way using the Windows API became apparent, I found and excellent summation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID.

Using the CPUID instruction, one can derive the model based on the highest supported feature count, returned in the EAX register; coupled with vendor (returned elsewhere). I now have a nice abstraction layer for all this.

Here is a list of processors and the highest function supported: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID

For Skylake CPUs, this is 0x16 (32).

History shows this to be unique for CPU models (see link).

Comment: I don't think that's guaranteed to uniquely identify SKL vs. Kaby Lake, for example.  I wouldn't be surprised if KBL has the same supported feature set, because it's mostly just a power-optimized SKL.  I'm not aware of any actual design-changes other than using less power.  (Which enables higher turbo clocks more of the time, apparently giving significant speedups for laptop esp when gaming with integrated graphics, where the GPU is also competing for a share of the 15W TDP power budget.)

Comment: Skylake and above by Intel, I'm sorry. I was not precise enough in my writing. Would you then agree?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's not something I've looked into very much at all.  It's likely that future generations of the same family will only increase in number of CPUID queries supported, not decrease, so this sounds plausible.  (And SKL probably has more than Broadwell).  Although I might worry about a Broadwell-E (many-core Xeon) maybe having extra supported CPUID queries.

Comment: History seems to indicate that this is true, looking at the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID . In any event, I appreciate your input!